# How to make 'diff' output line-by-line?

Tags: diff

I have a seemingly simple question I can't find answer for.

Say, I have two files:

```
A
B
C
D
```

and

```
A
X
Y
D
```

When I run `diff -U 1000` on these, I get:

```
 A
-B
-C
+X
+Y
 D
```

Instead, I'd like to get:

```
 A
-B
+X
-C
+Y
 D
```

Big picture to understand what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a scheduled script that runs `smartctl` on my hard drives, keep the historic data, and compare them. So, the changed lines are, indeed, individual replacements for the corresponding lines of the earlier file:

```
-  3 Spin_Up_Time      0x0027   173   168   021    Pre-fail  Always    -    2350
-  4 Start_Stop_Count  0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always    -    4445
+  3 Spin_Up_Time      0x0027   172   168   021    Pre-fail  Always    -    2358
+  4 Start_Stop_Count  0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always    -    4461
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with a two-step process: passing to to `git diff` and then post-processing it with an AWK script:

```sh
     git diff --word-diff=porcelain -U10000 %1 %2  |
     awk -f mysmartdiff.awk;
```

The first step returns a result in the following form:

```
~
   3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027
-172
+173
    168   021    Pre-fail  Always       -
-2358
+2333
```

and the second script does this:

[image: screenshot of final result]

The `mysmartdiff.awk` script is the following:

```awk
BEGIN {
    DEBUG=0
    l1=""
    l2=""
    old=""
    new=""
}
function dprint(s) { if(DEBUG) {print s > "/dev/stderr"} }

function appendDiff() {
    if(length(old)!=0 || length(new)!=0) {
        l1 = l1"\033[1;31m"old"\033[0m"
        l2 = l2"\033[1;32m"new"\033[0m"
        old="";new="";
    }
}
{
    dprint(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    dprint("ORIG: " $0)
    if(match($0, /^ /)) {
        appendDiff();
        l1 = l1""substr($0,2)
        l2 = l2""gensub(/[^-]/, " ", "g", substr($0,2)); ## leave '-' to aid further space trimming
    } else if(match($0, /^~/)) {
        appendDiff();
        print l1;
        if(l2 !~ /^[ -]+$/) {
            print l2;
        }
        l1=""
        l2=""
    } else if(match($0, /^-/)) {
        old=substr($0,2);
    } else if(match($0, /^+/)) {
        new=substr($0,2);
    }
}
```